# PHP FPDF append image at end of existing PDF File

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I have a PHP application where I have to browse for an image from my desktop and add it to an existing PDF file saved in my project file.

Now, my PDF file already has around 5-6 images, and I need to add this image at the end of the PDF file.

I also don't know how to get the image to fit an entire page of the PDF files, which is why I set its parameters to:

```
      $pdf->Image($imagePath,0,0); //It is wrong I guess
```

Here is the code I have worked upon so far with Stack Overflow's help but it's not working at all, I get a few errors.

```
 <?php 
  use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;  //I just pasted this line not knowing how it works
  include 'header.php'; 
  require_once 'fpdf181/fpdf.php';
  require_once 'FPDI-2/src/autoload.php';
  require_once 'FPDI-2/src/Fpdi.php';
?>

<html>
<head>
       <script>
               var x; //stores image path, which is somewhat working
               function getImagePath()
               {
                  x = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0].name;
                  alert(x);
               }
      </script>
<head>

<body>
    <div id="container">

        //HTML Button to browse for an image
        <input type="file" id="myFile" size="50">

        //HTML Button to display image file path
        <button type = "button" onclick="getImagePath()">Check path</button>

        <?php 
            // initiate FPDI
            $pdf = new FPDI();

            // get the page count
            $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('fpdf_merge/ex.pdf');
            // iterate through all pages
            for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) 
            {
                // import a page
                $templateId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
                // get the size of the imported page
                $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);

                // create a page (landscape or portrait depending on the imported page size)
                if ($size['w'] > $size['h']) 
                    {
                        $pdf->AddPage('L', array($size['w'], $size['h']));
                    } 
                else 
                    {
                        $pdf->AddPage('P', array($size['w'], $size['h']));
                    }

                // use the imported page
                $pdf->useTemplate($templateId);
            }

            //this is where the error is occurring i.e Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Unsupported image type: write(x)</script>

            $imagePath = "<script>document.write(x)</script>"; 


            //the second error from below code: FPDF->Error('Unsupported ima...') #1 

            $pdf->Image($imagePath,0,0);

            // Output the new PDF
            $pdf->Output();  //Does this step save changes to the exisiting pdf?
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

The error is occurring when the image path is to be read from the JavaScript variable

```
Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Unsupported image type: write(x)</script>
```

The second error occurs when the image is to be added to the pdf

```
FPDF->Error('Unsupported ima...') #1
```

I am not sure how to go about solving this issue.

Comment: Well, you need to use a file - not a JavaScript code for $pdf->Image()

Comment: Um ohok, can you please share some reference code/link for it?

Comment: $imagePath = "/your/server/path/to/your/image.jpg";

Comment: Nope, its not working that way, is there any other way to work around it?